# Python asyncio performance on OS X vs Ubuntu

Tags: python, macos, ubuntu, tcp, python-asyncio

I have some issues with Python asyncio performance on OS X. I have Macbook pro 2015 with 16gb RAM. But can't get the same performance on OS X (El Capitan) as on Ubuntu. Even given the fact that I am running Ubuntu inside VM (vagrant, 4gb RAM) with OS X host.

OS X benchmark with wrk:

`wrk -t8 -d 10s -c 300 http://127.0.0.1:9090                                                                                                                  ⏎
Running 10s test @ http://127.0.0.1:9090
  8 threads and 300 connections
  Thread Stats   Avg      Stdev     Max   +/- Stdev
    Latency   628.63us    1.45ms  16.32ms   89.46%
    Req/Sec   696.05    834.65     5.51k    88.89%
  19498 requests in 10.08s, 361.78KB read
  Socket errors: connect 0, read 20482, write 0, timeout 0
Requests/sec:   1934.40
Transfer/sec:     35.89KB`

Ubuntu:

`wrk -t8 -d 10s -c 300 http://127.0.0.1:9090
Running 10s test @ http://127.0.0.1:9090
  8 threads and 300 connections
  Thread Stats   Avg      Stdev     Max   +/- Stdev
    Latency     5.49ms   14.33ms 408.97ms   99.22%
    Req/Sec     3.58k     1.41k    8.42k    70.91%
  204333 requests in 10.06s, 3.70MB read
  Socket errors: connect 0, read 3, write 977, timeout 0
Requests/sec:  20311.64
Transfer/sec:    376.88KB`

Server code: https://gist.github.com/ssbb/5f6c2c043880e0e917c3254d06c52a7e

`ulimit -a` on Ubuntu: https://gist.github.com/ssbb/e468b3ede5470da25699e4da4506b77c

`ulimit -a` on OS X: https://gist.github.com/ssbb/f2a846975069a1d62a313790ad8d26ce

`sysctl -a` on OS X: https://gist.github.com/ssbb/c78d5da7ae9e3670175f643309cf9f6b

`sysctl -a` on Ubuntu: https://gist.github.com/ssbb/9a00cc3856135369b16ddc0083d2bc88

Why I have so much difference between Ubuntu/OS X. Also I tried to run this server on Arch Linux (not VM, just second OS) and have the same results as OS X.

Do Ubuntu have some "hacks" for TCP stack?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MacOSX has slower network stack implementation that linux, it's well known fact.

I don't know why Arch Linux is slower than Ubuntu on your machine. Network stack is implemented by linux kernel itself, linux distros with the same kernel version should display almost the same performance.